# Unable to fectch dataset numerical value

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

```
<select class="license_type" name="license_type" id="license_type">
    <option value="l_one" data-one="500">License 1</option>
    <option value="l_two" data-two="700">License 2</option>
    <option value="l_three" data-three="1400">License 3</option>
</select>
```

These 500, 700, 1400 will later come programmatically through PHP. So my goal is to fetch them in JS through the dataset.

The JS function that I wrote is:

```
  function someFunction() {
    var vOne= document.getElementById("license_type");
    var vTow = vOne.options;
    var c1 = vTow.dataset.one;
    var c2 = vTow.dataset.two;
    var c3 = vTow.dataset.three;  
}
```

then in another JS instead of the hard coded prices like this :

```
  var prices = [500, 700, 1400];
```

and this:

```
  var prices = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'];
```

But this generates NAN that means c1, c2, c3 doesn't have numerical values.
whats the Fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems that it has three static options, so considering that below code will work.

```
function someFunction() {
    var license_type= document.getElementById("license_type");
    var c1 = license_type.options[0].getAttribute('data-one');
    var c2 = license_type.options[1].getAttribute('data-two');
    var c3 = license_type.options[2].getAttribute('data-three');
    var prices = [c1, c2, c3];
    console.log(prices)
}
```

But if the options are dynamic than you'll have to loop through the options.

Comment: Still not fetching the numerical value.

Comment: Yes, It worked. I hope there is no browser compatability issue?

Comment: what do you mean by if the options are dynamic? Any example?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getAttribute` and `parseInt`. Also loop through the options, and use destructuring like so:

```
function someFunction() {
    var vOne = document.getElementById("license_type");
    var options = vOne.getElementsByTagName("option");
    var [c1, c2, c3] = options.map(e => e.getAttribute("data-one"));
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise destructuring unless you're transpiling, as it is [not supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

First, I will use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all options of the target select. Then, I will use [Array::map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map all options to his `data-*` attribute. Note I have to get the second part of the name of `data-*` attribute from the `value` attribute, because the `data-*` attribute appears to be related to the `value` attribute (is not an uniform name):

```js
var prices;

function someFunction()
{
    var opts = document.querySelectorAll("#license_type option");

    prices = Object.values(opts).map(o =>
    {
        let token = o.getAttribute("value").match(/l_(\w+)/)[1];
        return o.getAttribute("data-" + token);        
    });

    console.log(prices);
}

someFunction();
```

```html
<select class="license_type" name="license_type" id="license_type">
    <option value="l_one" data-one="500">License 1</option>
    <option value="l_two" data-two="700">License 2</option>
    <option value="l_three" data-three="1400">License 3</option>
</select>
```